# Compile directives via service in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I'm trying to compile directive via angular service but unfortunately it doesn't work.
The idea is to show errors in popups.

I've modified **$exceptionHandler** service:

```
crm.factory('$exceptionHandler', function(popup) {
    return function(exception) {
        popup.open({message: exception});
    }
});
```

The **popup** service looks like this:

```
crm.factory('popup', function ($document) {
    return {
        open: function (data) {
            var injector = angular.element(document).injector(),
                $compile = injector.get('$compile'),
                template = angular.element('<popup></popup>');

            // var ctmp = $compile(template.contents());
            $compile(template.contents());

            $document.find('body').append(template);
        }
    };
});
```

And I don't think that this was a good idea to hard code **$compile** service (but I haven't any ideas how to realize this in angular):

```
$compile = injector.get('$compile')
```

**Popup directive**:

```
crm.directive('popup', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/public/js/templates/common/popup.html',
        link: function() {
            console.log('link()');
        },
        controller: function () {
            console.log('ctrl()');
        }
    };
});
```

May be there are some other ways to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject `$compile` directly into your service, also you're not quite using `$compile` correctly:

```
//commented alternative lines for allowing injection and minification since reflection on the minified code won't work
//crm.factory('popup', ['$document', '$compile', function ($document, $compile) {
crm.factory('popup', function ($document, $compile) {
    return {
        open: function (data) {
            var template = angular.element('<popup></popup>'),
                compiled = $compile(template);

            $document.find('body').append(compiled);
        }
    };
});
//closing bracket for alternative definition that allows minification
//}]);
```

Comment: nope, i can't use it directly. The error looks like: "Uncaught Error: Circular dependency: $compile <- popup <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope"

Comment: Doesn't work in Angular 1.2, it asks for the scope as a parameter

Comment: to fix that you can inject `$rootScope` and do `$rootScope.$new()` to create a new scope, updated the answer.